# Getting a certain part of the string in Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a string "From City1 To City2 By Bus". I want last part "Bus". How can I achieve it through SQL Query. From, To and By are constant.

Comment: are you always looking for the last word, or the word you are looking for can occur anywhere in the string? In any case, I would recommend doing this in your program instead of database level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more flexible approach if your word is always at the end of the sentence:

```
declare @text varchar (max) = 'From City1 To City2 By Bus'

select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@text),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@text) )))
```

Comment: could you accept/upvote my answer if that's the case ?

Comment: ya Sure. It helps me alot

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your sql query:

```
RIGHT(LEN("From City1 To City2 By Bus")-PATINDEX('%By%',"From City1 To City2 By Bus")-3)
```

You can replace the string in the function above with a column name. The function above looks for the word "By", and returns what comes after it.

[Link: Microsoft documentation on string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)